# Let f(z) be a holomorphic function which takes only pure imaginary values. Show that f is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let f(z) be a holomorphic function which takes only pure imaginary values.
Show that f is constant.

I am a little stuck with this as I have noted that $z=u+iv$ where $u=0$ hence $du/dx=du/dy=0$ so by the Cauchy riemann equations $dv/dx=dv/dy=0$ and hence integration we have v is a constant but I'm lost on how to show that f is constant?

where do we take the function in this?

Comment: Since $f$ is holomorphic, the fact that these four partial derivatives are zero is enough to guarantee that $f' = 0$.

Comment: Is there a formula for $f'$ in these partial derivatives?

Comment: Yes, if we view $f$ as a real function $(u(x, y), v(x, y))$, the derivative is the usual Jacobian matrix.

Comment: By definition of $f'(z_0)$, as $z \to z_0$ : $f(z) = f(z_0)+ (z-z_0)f'(z_0)+o(|z-z_0|)$. Now if $f'(z_0) \ne 0$ and $f(z_0)$  is imaginary, then $f(z)$ won't be imaginary for every $z$ in the neighborhood of $z_0$.